# Texture not applying to shape in proccessing

Tags: java, processing, textures

I am trying to apply a image to the shape ive created. Each time the deforstation button is clicked it creates a graph and im trying to apply the picture i have in the folder as the texture so the shape is filled with trees instead of just black. i will add textures for the sea level and c02 as well so it changes for each graph i just want to figure the forest one out first so in the forest button i make the img variable as the forest picture.

i get an error code in when i run in the console that says texture() is not available with this renderer.

```
Table table;
IntList yearList;
IntList graphedData;
String fileName;
String name;
PImage img;

void loadLabelsAndButtons() {
  // Draw sea level button
  fill(255); // added fill color

  //c02 button
  rect(50, 560, 150, 30, 18);
  textSize(12);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  text("c02 Increase ", 120, 580);


  //sealevel button
  fill(255); // added fill color
  rect(250, 560, 150, 30, 18);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  text("Sea increase", 320, 580);

  //deaforstation button
  fill(255); // added fill color
  rect(450, 560, 150, 30, 18);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  text("Deforestation", 520, 580);
}

void setup() {
  size(700, 600);
  loadLabelsAndButtons();
}

void draw() {
}

void mousePressed() {
 //sky map button
  if (mouseX > 50 && mouseX < 200 && mouseY > 560 && mouseY < 590) {
    //calls forest map

    drawGraph("sky.csv");
    textSize(20);
    text("Global c02 increase scince 1960", 350, 100);
    textSize(12);
    text("(Million metric tons)", 350, 125);
    fill(128,128,128);
    text("(Source: Global Carbon Project:)", 350, 145);
  }
   //sealevel map button
  if (mouseX > 250 && mouseX < 400 && mouseY > 560 && mouseY < 590) {
    //calls seaslevel map
    drawGraph("seaLevel.csv");
    textSize(20);
    text("United States sea-level increase scince 1960", 350, 100);
    textSize(12);
    text("(Millimeters)", 350, 125);
    fill(128,128,128);
    text("(Source:NOAA)", 350, 145);

  }
   //forest map button
  if (mouseX > 450 && mouseX < 600 && mouseY > 560 && mouseY < 590) {
    //calls forest map
**    img = loadImage("tree.jpg");
**    drawGraph("deforest.csv");
    
    textSize(20);
    text("Global deforestation scince 1960", 350, 100);
    textSize(12);
    text("(Million Hectares)", 350, 125);
    fill(128,128,128);
    text("(Source: Worl Data:)", 350, 145);

  }
}

void drawGraph(String name) {
  background(255);
  //clear canvas
  loadLabelsAndButtons();

  //getsdata for new graph to draw
  parseData(name);

  //creates x axis
  yearText();
  int y = 600;
  int x = 50;
  int v = 0;
**
  textureMode(NORMAL);
  texture(img);**

  beginShape();
  for (v = 0; v < yearList.size(); v++) {

    texture(img);
    y = graphedData.get(v);

    // align to the middle of the screen
    vertex(x, (900 - y) / 2 + 50);
    x = x + 50;
  }
  vertex(x-50, 900/2 + 50); // add vertex to complete the shape
  endShape();
  yearText();
}

//gets data for graphs from each spreadsheet
void parseData(String fileName) {
  //water levels
  yearList = new IntList();
  graphedData = new IntList();
  table = loadTable(fileName, "header");
  for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {
    int year = row.getInt("Year");
    int yValue = row.getInt("Rise");
    yearList.append(year);
    graphedData.append(yValue);
  }
}

//headers for x axis
void yearText() {
  int y = 0;
  int yText = 0;
  int x = 50;
  int v = 0;
  int xText = 0;
  for (v = 0; v < yearList.size(); v++) {
    yText = graphedData.get(v);
    xText = yearList.get(v);
    y = (900 - yText) / 2 + 50;
    fill(0);
    textSize(12);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(yText, x, y - 10);
    text(xText, x, 550);
    x = x + 50;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using (`texture()`) is throwing this error, because this function only work with the P3D and OPENGL renderers in Processing. To fix this you should add P3D in your size at setup. Here is what is should look:

```
void setup() {
  size(700, 600, P3D); 
  loadLabelsAndButtons();
}
```

Comment: i tried that and it did change the color of the shapes to a grey but i dont know how it got that color but it didnt change texture

Comment: Try creating a new sketch, adding ```the setup()``` and ```draw()``` functions, and adding the line ```img = loadImage("tree.jpg");``` to the ```setup()``` function. If the image does not load properly in this new sketch, it may be corrupted or in an unsupported format.